# Using (Open)VPN as proxy only with certain apps

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy

My Firefox connects to the internet using an SSH tunnel through a server. The advantage of this is that I can setup some apps to use the tunnel using their proxy options, while others never do (some of my apps are dependent on geolocation and masking my IP would create problems).

I'd like to use a paid OpenVPN service for Firefox and a few other apps so that my web traffic isn't linked to the aforementioned server, but make sure that other apps *never* connect via VPN. Is it possible to set up OpenVPN (or if not, other types of VPN) to act this way?